# How I can grep data with some spaces and ignoring block?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, regular-expression, netstat

I am trying to retrieve `Local Address`-port with port number in different block used by each IP-address in `Foreign Address` and `PID/Program name`) from the following and store it in a file:

I used:

```
    netstat -natp | grep '^[a-z0-9P]*'
```

after that I want to ignore `Recv-Q` and `Send-Q` block and take `Local Address` with its port number and `Foreign Address` and then again ignore `State` and take `PID/Program name`.

Which regexp will be help full for me? Also, it will be more helpful if I am able keep both port numbers in different block after each address.

This is What I have:

```
$ netstat -natp | grep '^[a-z0-9P]*'
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7071            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:37960    106.10.218.42:443       ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:35636    117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        1     32 192.168.42.157:40444    5.39.93.71:443          CLOSING     -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:35626    52.27.200.224:443       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:43004    122.252.255.200:80      ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:35734    117.18.237.29:80        TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:35776    52.27.200.224:443       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:41690    54.182.1.219:443        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:56472    54.182.0.97:443         ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        1     32 192.168.42.157:48390    198.252.206.25:443      CLOSING     -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:37322    34.107.221.82:80        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:57724    204.79.197.204:443      ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:43142    23.57.14.17:443         ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:46286    13.227.138.58:443       ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:55576    112.133.250.163:443     ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:52328    151.101.120.193:443     ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:35736    52.39.214.89:443        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:57252    99.83.135.170:443       ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:48394    198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:45020    54.182.0.113:443        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:50396    27.123.42.205:443       ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        1     32 192.168.42.157:48092    198.252.206.25:443      CLOSING     -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:55798    142.250.192.99:80       TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:34190    157.240.16.52:443       ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:37320    34.107.221.82:80        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:44806    54.87.110.85:443        ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox       
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.157:51202    103.229.10.173:443      ESTABLISHED 21019/firefox
```

This is what I want:

```
Prot Local Address PortofLocalA  Foreign Address  PortofForeignA  PID/Program name
```

and all its o/p below it

Comment: Not sure your `grep '...' `  does anything at all there. Why do you need it at all ?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: What does _"port in different block"_ means ? Do you mean to separate port from IP address and print them in a different ***columns*** ? Please Edit your question to clarify your desired output if possible with awell formated  example-output in your post. Notify me with @Cbhihe in a comment.

Comment: switch to `ss` let you save a lot of post processing headcache

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: No, you can't do this with grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although kludgy, you can try this:

```
$ netstat -natp 2> /dev/null | awk 'NR==2 {printf("%s\t%s %s\t%s %s\t%s %s\n",$1,$4,$5,$6,$7,$9,$10)}
                                    NR>=3 {OFS="\t";print($1,$4,$5,$7)}'
```

***EDIT***
... and, for the sake of completion if you need the port column separate from its IP direction in your final output, you can introduce a finer grained formatting in `awk`, like so:

```
  $ netstat -natp 2>/dev/null | awk '
      NR==2 {printf("%s\t%8s %s\tPort\t%8s %s\tPort\t%s\n",$1,$4,$5,$6,$7,$9)} 
      NR>=3 {$8=$7;
             idx=match($5,":[^:]+$");
             $7=substr($5,idx+1);
             $6=substr($5,1,idx-1);
             idx=match($4,":[^:]+$");
             $5=substr($4,idx+1);
             $4=substr($4,1,idx-1);
             printf("%s\t%16s\t%s\t%16s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8)}
     '
  Proto      Local Address        Port     Foreign Address        Port    PID/Program
  tcp              0.0.0.0        22               0.0.0.0        *       -
  tcp            127.0.0.1        631              0.0.0.0        *       -
  tcp            127.0.0.1        25               0.0.0.0        *       -
  tcp              0.0.0.0        445              0.0.0.0        *       -
  tcp            127.0.0.1        12150            0.0.0.0        *       -
  tcp              0.0.0.0        139              0.0.0.0        *       -
  tcp            127.0.0.1        37580          127.0.0.1        12150   2962/firefox
  tcp            127.0.0.1        12150          127.0.0.1        40684   -
  [...]
  tcp            127.0.0.1        12150           127.0.0.1       47646   -
  tcp            127.0.0.1        12150           127.0.0.1       48982   -
  tcp            127.0.0.1        12150           127.0.0.1       1414   -
  tcp6                  ::        22                    ::        *       -
  tcp6                 ::1        631                   ::        *       -     
  tcp6                  ::        445                   ::        *       -     
  tcp6                  ::        139                   ::        *       -
```

Tested with Gawk (GNU Awk) v5.1.0, where above sample output is from a random box lying about near me.

Differences with my earlier answer are:

- for each record's fields 4 and 5, check the position (`idx`) of the last `:` character in the string. Whatever comes after that is the port. The beginning of the string is the IP. That goes for both IPv4 and IPv6 IP strings. This is useful in separating IP and port number in `127.0.0.1:12345` and also in `::1:432` for instance.
- lose the `OFS="\t"` to specify the *output field separator* in the second `awk` block and add integer widths in appropriate places between `%` and `s` in the `printf` formatting strings in both `awk` blocks.

Comment: ty worked.. but is there any way to do it by grep ?

Comment: @TechParinda why do you want to do it with grep?

Comment: Does not work well for tcp6.

Comment: @ibuprofen. Tx. Fixed.

Comment: grep selects lines, not columns.  It's the wrong tool for this.  What's wrong with awk?

Comment: +1, The ipv6 scheme makes things ugly. Have not looked into it, but using `:` as a separator when it already is used for port is kind of strange. *New things* seems to make things harder lol. Like the old dev's `sdX[NR]` now `nvmpe0n1...` and what not, or `eno[N]` vs `enp\d\w\d+` - :D

Answer (score 0):

Not picture perfect, but as a start:

```perl
perl -ae 'printf("%-6s%16s%7s%16s%7s %7s %s\n", $F[0], $F[3] =~ /(.*):(.*)/, 
$F[4] =~ /(.*):(.*)/, $F[6] =~ /(\d*)\/?(.*)/) if $. > 2'
```

Out (Header added after the fact):

```
Proto    Local-Address   Port  Remote-Address   Port     PID  Program-name
tcp    192.168.122.100     53         0.0.0.0      *          -
tcp           10.0.0.8     53         0.0.0.0      *          -
tcp          127.0.0.1   9321       127.0.0.1  45396          -
tcp           10.0.0.8  45454  123.123.123.25    443     484  firefox
tcp          127.0.0.1  36363       127.0.0.1   3639   23018  weechat
tcp           10.0.0.8  23232  123.232.123.25    443     484  firefox
tcp           10.0.0.8  13131   22.123.123.33   6667   23415  irssi
tcp           10.0.0.8  45586    52.42.50.123    443   20538  firefox
tcp6                ::     80              ::      *          -
tcp6                ::     22              ::      *          -
tcp6               ::1    631              ::      *          -
tcp6                ::     25              ::      *          -
tcp6                ::    443              ::      *          -
tcp6         127.0.0.1     80       127.0.0.1  46922          -
```

Comment: ty worked.. but is there any way to do it by grep

Comment: done check it.. sorry for inconvience